# Sort gridview column by clicking another column using c#

Tags: c#, sorting, telerik, radgridview

I have a `Telerik RadGridView` in which I've many columns and many rows. I want to sort the rows depending on many things in other columns. So I created a column "priority" which has the values `'1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3, 4'` etc. Now I want to sort this column by clicking on another columns header.

I tried this:

```
private void gvOverview_CellClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{  
    if (e.Column.Name == "WT")
    {
        if (currentGridView.Columns["priority"].SortOrder == RadSortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            currentGridView.Columns["priority"].Sort(RadSortOrder.Descending, false);
        }

        else if (currentGridView.Columns["priority"].SortOrder == RadSortOrder.Descending)
        {
            currentGridView.Columns["priority"].Sort(RadSortOrder.Ascending, false);
        }

        else
        {
            currentGridView.Columns["priority"].Sort(RadSortOrder.Ascending, false);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason the "priority" column doesn't sort properly. I have to say that the priority column is type `double`.

I also tried `SortDescriptor` but it didn't work as well.

Any suggestions?

Tyler